# How to refactor a static logic into a generic class that implements callback functions triggered by a parameter in C++

Tags: c++

I've written a small C++ program to call different functions based on the duration of a button press. Now I'd like to refactor this to be more generic and accessible from a class. Ideally I'd like to use the class in a similar way to this:

```
myduration buttonDuration()
myduration.add(*func1(1), *func2(4), *func3(8))
```

where the parameter is a numeric value to indicate after how many seconds the specific function is being called. 
I don't know where to start looking how to implement a class that would take callback functions with parameters as input.

My current code looks like this: ("Ticker" generates a time based interrupt and is being used here to count the number of passed seconds)

```
#include "mbed.h"

DigitalOut led1(LED1);
DigitalOut led2(LED2);
DigitalOut led3(LED3);
DigitalOut led4(LED4);

Serial pc(USBTX, USBRX);
Ticker ticker;

InterruptIn pb(p17);

void state1(void){
 led2 = !led2;
 }

 void state2(void){
 led3 = !led3;
 }

 void state3(void){
 led4 = !led4;
 }


// Global count variable
int volatile counter = 0;
int volatile STATE = 0;

void countCallback(void) {
    counter = counter + 1;
}
void stateEval(void) {
    if(counter >=1 && counter <=3){
        STATE = 1; 
        state1();
        }
    if (counter >= 4 && counter <=7){
        STATE = 2;
        state2();
        }
    if (counter >=8 && counter <=10){
        STATE = 3;
        state3();
        }
    pc.printf("STATE %d \n", STATE);
}

// pb Interrupt routine - is interrupt activated by a falling edge of pb input
void pb_hit_interrupt (void) {
    ticker.attach(countCallback, 1);
    counter = 0;         
}

void pb_release_interrupt (void) {
    ticker.detach();
    stateEval();
    counter = 0;
    STATE = 0;
   // pc.printf("Counter: %d \n", counter);
}

int main() {
    // Use internal pullup for pushbutton
    pb.mode(PullUp);
    // Delay for initial pullup to take effect
    wait(.01);
    // Attach the address of the interrupt handler routine for pushbutton
    pb.rise(&pb_release_interrupt);
    pb.fall(&pb_hit_interrupt);
    // Blink led1 in main routine forever while responding to pb changes
    // via interrupts that activate pb_hit_interrupt routine
    while (1) {
        led1 = !led1;
        wait(.5);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Code Review, not on Stack Overflow. It's about refactoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of std::map and upper/lower_bound should do the trick.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <map>

using state_caller = std::map<double , std::function<void()>>;


void after3()
{
    std::cout << "up to 3 seconds" << std::endl;
}

void after1()
{
    std::cout << "up to 1 seconds" << std::endl;
}

void after8()
{
    std::cout << "up to 8 seconds" << std::endl;
}

void handle(const state_caller& cs, double secs)
{
    auto i = cs.lower_bound(secs);
    if (i == cs.end())
    {
        std::cout << "no entry for this" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        i->second();
    }
}

int main()
{
    state_caller caller;
    caller.emplace(1, after1);
    caller.emplace(3, after3);
    caller.emplace(8, after8);

    handle(caller, 0.5);
    handle(caller, 2.9);
    handle(caller, 3.0);
    handle(caller, 10.0);
    return 0;
}
```

> but I don't have `std::map` available on my implementation.

Something like this perhaps? Again, `iostream` is just there to provide a demonstration framework. If you don't have the header `<algorithm>` handy (why on earth not?) then it's easy to write. There's an implementation of `std::find_if` here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct action
{
    int counter_limit;
    int new_state;
    void (*transition)(void);
};

void state1() {
    std::cout << __func__;
}
void state4() {
    std::cout << __func__;
}
void state8() {
    std::cout << __func__;
}

// note that action_table is ordered by ascending counter_limit, so std::find will find the lower
// entry where counter_limit > counter
const action action_table[] =
{
    { 4, 1, state1 },
    { 8, 2, state4 },
    { 11, 3, state8 },
};

int STATE =0;

void stateEval(int counter) {
    auto iaction = std::find_if(std::begin(action_table),
                                std::end(action_table),
                                [counter](const action& a) {
                                    return counter < a.counter_limit;
                                });
    if (iaction == std::end(action_table)) {
        // handle error here
    }
    else {
        STATE = iaction->new_state;
        iaction->transition();
    }
    std::cout << " : " << "counter = " << counter << ", STATE = " << STATE << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    for (int counter = 0 ; counter < 11; ++counter)
        stateEval(counter);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: using double as a key isn't great idea

Comment: @jonezq Why not? It's not for `hash_map`, but for intervals should work. Map is an ordered container, and each entry is a mark. It should probably be wrapped in a `class` which would semantically split registering marks and probing, so you don't accidentally insert stuff, when you miss. But the internal implementation would be like the one above.

Comment: i am talking bout precision, for example, 3.00000001 and 2.9999999 seconds  - which interval? 1-3 or 3-8. personally would use std::chrono

Comment: @jonezq completely agree. The actual data type of time measurement will be dictated by the application and environment. This answer was more about demonstrating that the standard library already has an out-of-the-box solution for the general problem at hand.

Comment: Thanks @RichardHodges!! I'm not sure if I can implement it as suggested as I am working on an embedded system and STL classes like iostream & maps seem to be not advisable to use but it certainly gave me a good idea on how I could solve my problem!

Comment: @jensstrümper std::map should be small enough to fit, certainly if optimised for space. If not, you can write your own map (just a sorted array of K,V pairs is enough). obviously ostream can be dumped in your version. that was just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: @RichardHodges  So I'm running into problems where I though there wouldn't be any. Unfortunately maps is indeed not available on mbed (the platform I am using) and I struggle with the proposed KV array. It would be a 2 dimensional array with different datatypes (function pointer and double) ? But didn't find much useful reference to that, apparently people are saying arrays with different data types are not possible in c++. Do I need to handle the array as char and cast to the required data type?

Comment: @jensstrümper updated answer with alternate non-map solution

Comment: @RichardHodges, so it appears that none of the STL libraries are working - if searched in the mbed forums I get different feedback. Some people are saying things like "map" or "algorithm" should work some others report these libraries are not working or only  partly. If I look in some example programs nobody is really using STL libraries. Anyways.....I started to implement a plain 2 dimensional array and a function that iterates through the array and evaluates the current and the next item to identify state.

Comment: @RichardHodges, also, I tried to compile your two examples locally but they both failed to compile. Any Idea why that is? /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.3.0/bin/g++-5 button_press.cpp 
button_press.cpp: In function 'void stateEval(int)':
button_press.cpp:33:10: error: 'iaction' does not name a type
     auto iaction = std::find_if(std::begin(action_table),
          ^
button_press.cpp:37:34: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
                                 });
                                  ^

Comment: @jensstrümper don't forget -std=c++11 or -std=c++14 on the command line. `auto` is a c++11 keyword.

Comment: @RichardHodges. Ok, that did the trick. Compiles fine now. Thanks again! Really appreciate that you rewrote my code twice!